# Multiple CSplitterWnd windows

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, mfc

My question is a bit vague - kindly bear with me.

I have 3 windows inherited from `CSplitterWnd` class. Imagine all of them arranged vertically side by side. I am trying to write a utility that takes a combined screenshot of the three windows. At my disposal is function which i want to use as a blackbox, if possible

```
SaveViewToImage( CWnd *, FILE * path)
```

This  function will take a pointer to `CWnd` and save it to a bitmap file. Currently this function is provided with the active window (of the 3 splitter windows) and a output file is saved to the path. Is there a way to reuse this function to save a screenshot of all 3 windows, not just the active one.

Comment: Those 3 splitter windows probably have a common parent window. Identify the parent window and take screen shot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Barmak. When I try to get the parent window i still only get the active window ( one of the 3) however when i try to get parentwindowframe i get the GUI screenshot of the entire app which is not what i want as it contains the menubars, toolbars etc

Comment: Can you perform the operation on each and then merge the three together?

Comment: *"I have 3 windows inherited from CSplitterWnd"* I think you mean 1 `CSplitterWnd` window? You probably have 3 `CView` or `CFormView` within this `CSplitterWnd` window. Your question is about finding windows. You should show some details about these classes and their relations, and maybe a picture. `GetParent()` should work if it's called from within a view class.